# How to solve goniometric equation where function arguments differ?

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

I'm preparing myself for exams and I stumbled over goniometric equation:

$$\cos^2x + \cos{2x}+1=0$$

Normally, those equations are solved by pretending that $\cos{x}$ is some variable $u$ and ending up with something like (in case of quadratic equation):

$$\cos{x} = a_1\\
\cos{x} = a_2$$

But since I cannot substitute $u$ for $\cos{x}$ what should I do? I had a wild idea of *removing* cosinus the way you can "*remove*" logarithms. But I don't think this is valid:

$$\cos^2x + \cos{2x}+1=0\\
\cos^2x + \cos{2x}+\cos{0}=0\\
x^2+2x+0 = 0
$$
Even if that was actually valid, what would I do with results for $x$? Can anyone explain the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: Use $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1$. Then the equation reduces to $\cos x = 0$ for which you know the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos^2x+\cos2x+1=0$$

$$\cos^2x+(2\cos^2x-1)+1=0$$

$$3\cos^2x=0$$

$$\cos x=0$$

$$x=\frac{\pi}{2},\;\frac{3\pi}{2}...$$

Comment: $$\cos x=0\implies x=(2n+1)\dfrac\pi2$$

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about those special formulas that can be used. Gotta learn them all I guess...

Comment: @TomášZato do you know the formula for $\cos(u+v)$?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way, using almost the same trigonometric relation that Lanier Freeman applied:

$$\cos^2x+\cos2x+1=0$$

$$\cos^2x+(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))+(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))=0$$

$$3\cos^2x=0$$